# object required error when there is a value

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting an object required error for cellP.value but the range has values...I can't seem to figure this one out...

```
rng3 = Worksheets("Populations").Range("A2:A20")

For Each cellP In rng3

    If cellP > 0 Then

        Debug.Print cellP.Value
```

Comment: You need to set rng3

Answer (score 5):

If you have not, include a `Dim` statement for `rng3`.

```
Dim rng3 As Range
```

Then change the syntax for setting the reference of `rng3`

```
Set rng3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Populations").Range("A2:A20")
```